# Why I can not modify the appereance of my title web site in google?

Tags: title, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have tried everithing I have thought, but I could not solve it. The problem is that when I search my website domain in Google it appears like this: 
[image: My title website in Google]

Which is different that the tittle I have configured with the plugin Wordpress SEO by Yoast:
[image: My title website in Yoast configuration]

I would like to know why I can not change this title.

Comment: have you set _Force Rewrite Titles_ in yoast title and meta settings?

Comment: Yes, I had set it, but the tittle does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t force Google to use your `title`, [they may change it in their SERPs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493507/1591669):

> […] we have algorithms that generate alternative titles […]

> Google's generation of page titles and descriptions (or "snippets") is completely automated and takes into account both the content of a page as well as references to it that appear on the web. […]